# dangers of returning NAN to indicate invalid input to a method that also sets NSError

Tags: objective-c, nan, nserror

I am writing a method that returns one (double) number based on an input parameter. Since some inputs will not have valid return values, I want the method to indicate failure, and to use NSError to provide details on the error. 
Apple says (Error Handling Guide) not to use the returned NSError object to determine failure, but to have the method return a BOOL true or false, and if false, then to inspect the NSError object.

I'm planning on returning NAN to indicate failure and checking for that, along with the NSError object, rather than wrapping the class to return a BOOL and another object. I (think I) understand the obvious problem if I forget to check for NAN and then use the value, but are there any other bad/evil consequences? The code would look something like this:

```
NSError *sphericErr;
double sphericValue= [densityForThickness: mixThickness error:&sphericErr];
if (NAN == sphericValue) {
    // advise user of the error using NSError class messages
}
```

Appreciate all comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, NAN == sphericValue will never, ever be true. NaN compares different to any number, including NaN. if (sphericValue != sphericValue) works just fine to detect an NaN.

The reason why you should return a value indicating the error, and pass an NSError* through a pointer, is that the NSError* pointer is optional. A caller should be able to call your method passing error:NULL. That's especially important if the caller just passes another NSError** that it received from its own caller. So you need some way other than the NSError* to indicate that there is an error.

You *can* use the return value as you suggested, except you are in trouble if you ever want to return an NaN without it being an error. So you might consider returning a bool, and passing a double* and a pointer to an NSError*.

If you turn all warnings on, the compiler will most likely if you do something that Apple *really* doesn't want you to do.

Comment: Much obliged! As you said, `if (NAN == sphericValue) `
always returns false. 
I would have never, ever thought to do  `if (sphericValue!=sphericValue) then...`